# Difference between generalization and specialization

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

I cannot seem to understand the difference because they seem very similar to me even though my lecture notes say they are opposites.

If we take this as an example:
[image]

Apparently the area in green is a generalization while the area in red is a specialization. But I don't understand because it looks to me like they can both be taken as generalizations.

Can someone please clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you interpret the directionality of the boxes. Generalization and Specialization are the exact opposites of each other, or rather two sides of the same coin. Generalization refers to the process of taking a bunch of class, extracting their shared attributes and placing those in a super class or base class, (the terminology depends on your favorite programming language). Specialization refers to the process of taking a single class and splitting it up into two or more instances that differ from each other.

In your example, if your data model started out with a Person class, and then later you realize that talking about "Persons" is too generic for your purposes. Then you introduce 4 different types of Persons, namely Student, General Staff, Lecturer and Tutor, all of which share the same attributes as Person. This process is called specialization. If then you decided that 3 of these types share some of the same attributes, and you introduce another Type to handle it, that process if called generalization.

But at the end of the day both terms represent an inheritance relationship between objects. You can say X is the parent of Y and Z (generalization), of you can say that Y and Z are the children of X (specialization).

Comment: So something like a every DVD having one unique genre will be modeled using generalisations right?

Comment: In this case, the DVD class is the generic class, and each genre will be a **specialization** of the DVD class (DramaDVD, ComedyDVD, etc.). On an unrelated note, it might be a better idea to have a Movie base class, and have the children be Drama Movie, Comedy Movie, etc. This is because DVD's can store things that aren't necessarily movies or music